# Баг в Pycharm или же это нормальное поведение PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, pycharm

На данный момент изучаю базу данных PostgreSql
И столкнулся с непониманием поведения в некоторых моментах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]


При загрузке 10 000 000 строк в базу данных и нажимания на навигационные кнопки(перелистывания списка: вперед - назад) - строки в базе данных начинают пропадать!
(самоудаляться - по не понятным мне закономерностям.
В первую очередь удаляются из базы самые первые строки.)

Вопрос:
Это глюк дефолтного плагина в Pycharm или же так и должно быть?
Если да - то почему?

P.S. В Плагине DataGrip наблюдается такое же(1 в 1) поведение..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
Это был не баг.
Необходимо было просто отсортировать данные:

```
SELECT t.*, CTID
FROM public.eurusd t
ORDER BY ticker ASC, dtyyyymmdd ASC, time ASC,
  open ASC, high ASC, low ASC, close ASC, vol ASC
LIMIT 10;
```